# Vuetify - image in v-data-table cell - only part of image is visible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

In a table of users I want to show avatar in a second column. The problem is that rows are too small so the image is not shown whole.

[image]

Table:

```
<v-data-table :headers="tableHeaders" :items="streamers">
  <template v-slot:item.avatar="{ }">
    <v-img :max-height="100" aspect-ratio="1" :src="'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRubQH1F3DZWpm3WYs5SKpQBSH_ocCYenGjkA&usqp=CAU'"/>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

How to make that the whole image is visible?

Answer (score 0):

Add `contain` prop to `v-img`. Reference to [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/#props-contain).